# Searching Through Two Collections in Mongodb using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two Collections in my MongoDB setup

```
1.Customers
2.Agents
```

They both have `first_name` property.

I want to run a search on both collections to fetch either a Customer or Agent whose first_name matches a particular string.

How can I achieve this using Mongoose?

What I have tried, but I don't think is the best approach is the below:

```
let customers = await Customer.find({first_name:"user supplied string"});
let agents = await Agent.find({first_name:"user supplied string"});

let results = [...customers, ...agents]; //But I don't think this is best practice.
```

Any insight would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think mongoose allows you to search both collections at the same time.

If you want to find ALL Customers and Agent whose name is "user supplied string", your query method seems to be correct, according to docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Unless you have other specific requirements like, the name should include, and not only equal to "userstring", or the results are to be sorted in a certain manner. Or returning only the most recent entries created.

Perhaps share why you don't think this is the best practice?